# django error in my code ,what does i do

Tags: python, django

```
from django.core.management import setup_environ
from register2 import settings
setup_environ(settings)


from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class AuthenticationRememberMeForm ( AuthenticationForm ):

            """
            Subclass of Django ``AuthenticationForm`` which adds a remember me checkbox.

            """

            remember_me = forms.BooleanField (
                label = _( 'Remember Me' ),
                initial = False,
                required = False,
                )

print AuthenticationRememberMeForm.remember_me


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\zjm_code\register2\b.py", line 26, in <module>
    print AuthenticationRememberMeForm['remember_me']
TypeError: 'DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass' object is unsubscriptable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The django `forms` module uses a metaclass to facilitate declarative syntax for form fields. As a consequence, you should consider `remember_me` to be a *field* of your form *instance*, not a class attribute. So accessing the field as so makes sense:

```
form = AuthenticationRememberMeForm()
field_obj = form.fields['remember_me']
```

or, similarly, the value:

```
form = AuthenticationRememberMeForm(data)
if form.is_valid():
    remember_me_value = form.cleaned_data['remember_me']
```

Obviously, `django.forms` is doing a bit of work behind the scenes to make this happen. If you want to understand how, check out the [relevant code](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/forms.py). If you just want to make your forms *work*, try to follow the [usage outlined in the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/).